# Less guards with an OR operator

Tags: css, less, mixins

I know Less guards can use the `and` operator, e.g.

```
when (@width > 50) and (@height > 50) { ... }
```

But is there a way to do an `or` statement? When trying the above with the word `or`, I get the error *CSS guard can only be used at the end of selector*. I also tried:

```
when (@width > 50), when (@height > 50) { ... }
```

But that results in the error *Guards are only currently allowed on a single selector*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a comma with no additional `when`:

```
.mixin (@a) when (@width > 50), (@height > 50) { ... }
```

Source:  http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature-guard-logical-operators

Comment: No problem. Not the most *logical* syntax hehe.